# Is there a window-picker-applet replacement for 11.10?

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use the GNOME Panel in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39069/how-do-i-use-the-gnome-panel-in-unity)

I was very used to the window-picker-applet in previous Ubuntu releases and I don't think I will get used to the new unity dock.

Is there a window-picker-applet replacement in 11.10 that shows the **open windows icons** *on the panel*?

**EDIT:** I was looking for som way to only have the top panel and **nothing else** but I have given up and now I am trying to get used with the unity launcher. One other thing that would be nice is if there where a way to make the launcher smaller than 32 pixels.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't already, you can install [gnome-session-fallback](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-session-fallback), log out, select GNOME Classic at the login screen, and login. There will be a window picker in the panel.

- [How to revert to GNOME Classic Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks but I would rather keep unity. I am really just looking for a way to have all the open windows displayed as small icons on the top panel.

Answer (score 0):

There are many panels to choose from. Gnome Panel 3 is available, but far from as mature as Gnome Panel 2. Xfce4 has a nice panel. So does LXDE. All three can be run with Unity.

I provided a rather extensive answer to this here: [How to have the Taskbar with Unity at the same time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77216/how-to-have-the-taskbar-with-unity-at-the-same-time/77236#77236). It provides details on how to install, try and remove all those three panels.

Comment: yes, that is a rather extensive answer. :-)  Not sure but if I understood it is only possible to add a NEW panel? I am really looking for a solution that uses the current default upper panel.

Comment: You can have the upper panel from Unity and add other panels at the bottom. Moving the Unity panel to the bottom isn't possible, and wouldn't make much sense as long as it's used to integrate window titlebar, menu and controls.

Comment: Oh, maybe you mean that menu you had in Gnome Panel? An icon that displays a menu with all open windows when you click on it? I don't know of any such indicator, but it would be possible to make one.

Comment: I have given up and now I am trying to get used with the unity launcher.