# Multi-Workspace Compatible Taskbar in Unity 3D

Tags: 12.04, workspaces, taskbar

I'm currently using tint2, which doesn't seem to support workspaces in Unity 3D very well.  It can't keep windows in different workspaces in the correct taskbar (all workspaces show left monitor's tasks on left monitor, all workspaces show right monitor's tasks on right monitor).

However, it works great in Unity 2D.  Are there any alternatives that support this without having to drop down to the 2D interface?  I can't seem to find anything even remotely close to it.

(I'm hoping for something as similar to Window's taskbars as possible - not a dock).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon more searching, I found another answer which worked out beautifully.

https://askubuntu.com/a/77236/47004

"xfce4-panel" works great as a bottom taskbar and was quite easy to configure.

Answer (score 0):

There is also tint2

http://code.google.com/p/tint2/wiki/Install#For_Ubuntu_9.10_and_upwards

blah blah blah 30 characters