# separate panels in unity 5 on precise?

Tags: 12.04, unity, unity-dash, customization

Is it possible to create separate panels in unity on precise 12.04. Like in gnome you did a new panel and you put it where you want, autohide it or not??

Is this possible if yes how and if not why ?

Maybe somebody has an answer. i switched these days from lucid to precise. i like unity but some things are a bit long to reach. I'd like to make like a gnome menu. because to reach programs using the dash or the super key is not the maximum (dash is slow and super key yu have to know the name)

Thanks for reply

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/77216/how-to-have-the-taskbar-with-unity-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 2):

> Is this possible?

No

> if yes how and if not why ?

Because it is design decision

If you want classic appearance try gnome-session-fallback
Instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

[How to revert to GNOME Classic Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

Comment: Also, one can use [this](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/classicmenu-indicator/) ClassicMenu indicator from Unity environment.

Comment: @Samik I know , but how it realated to this question ?

Comment: OP says "I'd like to make like a gnome menu." he also said in his [original post](http://askubuntu.com/revisions/155812/1) that he likes Unity. So thought that'd be another alternative.

Comment: It's also possible to use other panels, docks and similar programs, like `tint2` or `gnome-panel` with Unity, but only in addition to the Unity panel and launcher, not as a replacement.

Comment: thanks for your ideas. the gnome panel didn't work on my precise (cannot use the take off the things)

Installed the classic menu like @Samik proposed. this is just something i wanted to. (would be nice on the launcher) The idea from Florian Diesch i have to say maybe it doesn't work in precise? I looked a bit arount the tutorials i found they were all on 11.04!?

thanks